# MPMediaQuery in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios-simulator, mpmediaquery

I want to run some tests on my iOS application and I would like to find a way to test in the simulator a **MPMediaQuery** so I can get a **MPMediaItemCollection** with mock data.
Any library or mock data I can use to test it without depending on a device?

Thanks,
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to test this onto simulator as there is no iTunes or Music app that manages mp3 files. You really need a device.